# Process identification using python multiprocessing library

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using python multiprocessing library for creating new processes. The parent needs to identify the child processes so it can stop a particular process anytime. I can give the name to a process but is it possible to get a process handler, to stop it later, using name?

Comment: Are you creating all of the processes at one time or just when required?

Comment: Could you just put the processes in a dict, with the name as the key?

Comment: Please show a trimmed down of your work. That makes it easier for those who can help.

Comment: @dano Thanks. I also thought about that after posting the message.

Comment: @justcompile I need to create processes when required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for the [terminate()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) method on your [multiprocessing.Process](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) instance.

Example usage of some of the methods of Process:

```
>>> import multiprocessing, time, signal
>>> p = multiprocessing.Process(target=time.sleep, args=(1000,))
>>> print(p, p.is_alive())
<Process(Process-1, initial)> False
>>> p.start()
>>> print(p, p.is_alive())
<Process(Process-1, started)> True
>>> p.terminate()
>>> time.sleep(0.1)
>>> print(p, p.is_alive())
<Process(Process-1, stopped[SIGTERM])> False
>>> p.exitcode == -signal.SIGTERM
True
```

If you are trying to get an active process by name, you could use the following function:

```
def get_process(name):
    return next((p for p in multiprocessing.active_children() if p.name == name), None)
```

Comment: Actually, I was looking for a function to get a process by name. I will store the processes in a dictionary and later use that to terminate the specific process.

Comment: @UsmanIjaz  A function has been added for getting a process by name.